# What does the term "centromere linkage" mean in genetics?

Tags: genetics, yeast, recombination, genetic-linkage

I am currently learning about tetrad/linkage analysis in yeast. I have read two statements similar to this:

> If two genes are unlinked, but linked to the centromere the distribution will be 50 parental ditype (PD) and 50% non-parental ditype (NPD).
> If two genes are unlinked, and unlinked to the centromere the distribution will be 1:1:4 in PD:NPD:TT

But I don't quite understand what the term linked to centromere means. I understand that two genes can be linked to each other if they are close together on the same chromosome.

So near the centromere no crossing-over occurs, so does "linked to centromere" just mean that there is no recombination taking place, as it is the case with the first statement?